# SQL cursors and space in tempdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, pymssql

I have a cursor which iterates over a million rows of a table and add two columns which contains a concatenated string based on certain join and rules from different table and then appends to the table columns. The cursor takes about 5 mins to run.

However, the issue is when query is executed it increases the size of tempdb exponentially and eventually maxing out to the full disk space.

After my cursor use I close the and deallocate the cursor. Just not sure why tempdb is not cleared up. Is there any way to make sure it gets clear up.

Comment: It sounds like you can do the processing without a cursor.  Can you show your existing code, as well as sample data and desired results?

Comment: Yeah agreed with Gordon this sounds like it can be solved in a Set based way. Show us some code and we can help you resolve that. A cursor is the old man at the liquor store that curses you when you dont give him spare change....